# Express 'res.render' Error: Rendering page multiple times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using a simple query to find a value in a database, as I return to a page it renders the page once correctly with the object that was retrieved, then renders it again with a null object (none was found), and the console.log files are being run twice, once with the correct data, once with nothing.  Is this a problem with express?

```
 app.get('/user/:userid',isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        var newmodel;
        mongoose.model('studentusers').find({ "userid" : req.params.userid }, function(err, docs){ //search for specific object that matches parameters
             console.log("DOCS: " + docs); //Check to see if the query worked
             //Here I just do some formatting on the object to be able to 
             var model = docs;
             model = JSON.stringify(model);
             model = model.replace("[", "");
             model = model.replace("]", "");
             console.log("model: " + model);//check to see if model is correct
             newmodel = JSON.parse(model);

            //The res.render returns the page once with the 'DOCS:' and 'model:' console.log files outputting the json info, and then again with nothing afterwards
             res.render('user.ejs',
                {
                    student: newmodel,
                });        
        });         
    });
```

So then after I see a correct output from 'DOCS:' and 'model:' it shows 'DOCS:' and 'model:' again, except empty, and I get this error:

```css
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at Promise.<anonymous>
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with `model`. Why are you removing `[` and `]` from the JSON string? That might be what's causing your error. To be sure, run the contents of `model` through a JSON linter.

Comment: Ok, so initially it was outputting a strange form of an object which is why I reverted to the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse methods to be able to get it in a good form.  I figured that since docs outputs in model form the <%=student.userid%> reference or whatever else I try to reference in the object should show up in the template .ejs page.  When I remove the JSON formatting however it doesn't work either.  I can try JSON.lint assuming it does a similar thing from what I have read.

Comment: With jsonlint.parse(model) I get the same value as when I just try to set student : docs,  directly under the res.render code.  For some reason the template references <%=student.name %> etc all return undefined and I am still seeing multiple outputs of DOCS and model: being displayed

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to find one user, not multiple users. In this case the `docs` variable will be an array, not a single document. Try changing your query to use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Comment: @BrianShamblen: 'findOne' did seem to get the page displaying the data correctly! Even though it all works and the site doesn't break,  I still am getting a 500 error and type error where DOCS: null, after it returns correctly  and where the attributes of the docs array is reference by the student (ex <%=student.userid%>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have any of the code that converts the `docs` object to the `newmodel` object. That's all extraneous, because `find` returns an array. If you convert the mongoose call to use the `findOne` method you should simply be able to do this:

```
app.get('/user/:userid',isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    mongoose.model('studentusers').findOne({userid: req.params.userid }, function(err, user){ 
        res.render('user.ejs', {student: user});        
    });         
});
```

Comment: Yeah this worked great!  Thought I tried this before, but something else must have been breaking it.  Thanks a bunch!